# Manufacturing, qualification and sale

Tags: prototyping, development, manufacturing

I'm thinking about selling a small batch of a simple gadget that would have some electronics inside.

If I want to use an online shop and sell it worldwide, what are the certifications and licenses to be aware of?

If I qualify something for the UE, can it be sold to the USA?

Comment: Tags are absurd because I wasn't able to create new ones.

Comment: Tags are based on reputation...you couldn't have just anyone logging in an creating / changing them...all you would get would be profanity and off topic conversation.

Comment: ppvi: I sympathize. I posted a feature request about this on stackexchange's website. In the meantime, just post a request for someone else to add them in a comment.

Comment: I can create a new account and ask a question (which has a large bold title) with profanity and off topic conversation, but I can't create my own tags (which are much smaller than the title)? Seems a little misguided, especially for bootstrapping new communities who don't have a whole lot of high ranking users or tons of tags already created.

Comment: Note: I was forced to add tags. But only existing ones.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

If it's a consumer gadget/toy (and not a medical device which has much more stringent standards!) you probably just need to worry about safety standards and EMC standards.

- CE declaration for Europe
- EMC certification: in the USA, [FCC class B](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Title_47_CFR_Part_15) radiated emissions
- Europe now requires [RoHS](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Restriction_of_Hazardous_Substances_Directive) to limit Cd, Pb, Hg and some other hazardous substances

Safety standards will include things like pinch points, sharp edges; if it's a toy and there are children involved, there's a standard container used for choke hazards, etc. If the gadget plugs into the wall for power, you need to worry about shock hazards and fire hazards ([UL](http://www.ul.com/global/eng/pages/) in the USA), although you can probably deal with this by using a UL/CE approved wall transformer so voltages entering your device are limited.

Comment: I'd like to stress that using UL-listed wall transformers are a great way to sidestep some of the certification issues, but make sure you understand what you're using.  You probably still need to do some power regulation/filtering in your product as well.  Good answer!

Answer (score 5):

If it's a small batch, and you're using an approved wall transformer as mentioned by Jason S, you probably don't have to worry about anything. I've seen all sorts of sites selling little gadgets they make in small quantity, that I am 99% sure they didn't do any kind of certification. It all depends on the scale...does 'small batch' mean 20 or 2000?